# Deprecate entire model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, model, deprecated

I'm in the process of rewriting/refactoring a legacy application for a client from Rails 2.x to 3.x. As part of the refactoring I also want to step away from models/methods in our local language to a pure English code base.

This involves writing new methods for almost every feature. I solve this for methods by doing:

```ruby
def english_method
  # ...
end

def native_method
  warn 'DEPRECATED, please use #english_method'
  english_method
end
```

This works fine for methods, and helps me track places where the old method is still being used, without breaking any code.

For classes (models) however, I've been doing:

```ruby
class NativeClass < EnglishClass
  # DEPRECATED, Please use EnglishClass
end

class EnglishClass
  # ...
end
```

This "works", whenever `NativeClass` is called, the application keeps working, but I don't get any message in the log notifying me of a part of the application still calling `NativeClass`.

How can I make sure every "touch" of `NativeClass` actually results in a log error being written?

I tried (for no reason other than thinking "maybe this works") to do:

```ruby
class NativeClass < EnglishClass
  -> { ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn 'Native model is deprecated in favor of English' }
end
```

But that (obviously?) didn't work. I figure the lambda would be lazy loaded every time `NativeClass` is called, but my understanding of lambdas is still somewhat shallow, so I might be mistaken here.

Any clues on how to deprecate entire classes and send a warning message to my log when it's being touched?

Other "best practices" and or solutions for deprecation are welcome, but I'm not sure if it's a valid question for SO (and I don't want to risk this topic getting closed for this question).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use like:

```
class NativeClass < EnglishClass
  def initialize
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "NativeClass is deprecated and may be removed from future releases, use EnglishClass instead.", caller
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with this solution (as far as I know, and tested), is that the initialize method is only triggered if I create a new class object. If I call methods on the class itself, or on constants defined in the class, this isn't triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off just deprecating each method individually. This can easily be accomplished by using Rails' deprecate method and passing it a list of methods you want to deprecate. The list of methods defined within a class is available by passing false to `public_instance_methods`

```
class NativeClass < EnglishClass
  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  deprecate *public_instance_methods(false)
end
```

Note that it needs to be declared AFTER the last public method.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to deprecate all methods (just yet), I just want to deprecate the Class name for now. So I still want all the methods to remain the same, I just want the warning when the method is called using the deprecated class name. I could possibly a new `deprecate` method which I insert in all other methods, but I was hoping for an easier solution.